Is there a formula for the natural logarithm that works on non-numeric inputs?
Because $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty{\frac{x^n}{n!}}$, any value that can be multiplied by itself and divided by an integer can be used as an exponent.
For example, $e^{\begin{bmatrix}0 & -\pi \\ \pi & 0\end{bmatrix}}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$.
And because $e^{ln(a)}=a$, that means $ln(\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix})=\begin{bmatrix}0 & -\pi \\ \pi & 0\end{bmatrix}$.
So as long as $ln(a)b$ can be multiplied by itself and divided by an integer, you can compute the value of $a^b$.
Is there a formula for the natural logarithm that can be applied to non-numeric values?
That is, is there a way to discover the value of $ln(\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix})$ or $ln(f)$ without stumbling upon the expontent for $e$ that results in that value by chance?

Use the Taylor series of the logarithm.

In the real numbers $e^A=B$ implies $A=\ln B$ because the function $e^x$ is injnective. That is no longer the case in the complex numbers, for example, and also not the case with $2\times2$ matrices. Indeed, $e^{\begin{bmatrix}0 & -k\pi \ k\pi & 0\end{bmatrix}}=\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 \ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$ for any odd integer $k$. So the logarithm is not so straightforward to define.

There’s a pretty nice discussion here.

As others suggested, you can use the Maclaurin series for the function $\ln(x+1)$:
$\ln (x+1)=x-\frac {x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\frac{x^5}5-...=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}x^n}n$
This way you can define logarithm on any ring.
In the case of $2\times2$ matrices, you will get:
$\ln \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}-a+d\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)+\left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a-d\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}} & \frac{b \left(\ln \left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)-\ln \left(-\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}} \\
 \frac{c \left(\ln \left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)-\ln \left(-\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)}{\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}} & \frac{\left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a-d\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(-\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)+\left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}-a+d\right) \ln \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}+a+d\right)\right)}{2 \sqrt{(a-d)^2+4 b c}} \\
\end{array}
\right)$
